# Составить логику поиска по базе mysql через php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Есть скрипт search.php который смотрит базу

```
<?php

$dbuser = "****";
$password = "****";
$server = "*****";
$database = "*****";
$table = "shop";

$link = mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use ' . $database . ' : ' . mysql_error());
}


$arr = array();

if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
$term = $_GET['term'];
$query2 = "SELECT name1 FROM `shop` WHERE `article` LIKE '%$term%' OR `name1` LIKE '%$term%'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) 
or die();

while($ans = mysql_fetch_row($result2)){

$arr[] = $ans[0];
}

echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

так же есть jq который выводит это в `autocomplete`

```
$(function() {
function log( message ) {
$( "#result" ).text(message);
$( "body" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}
$( "#searchword" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
minlength: 1,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected Topic: " + ui.item.value :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
});
```

а вот пример строчки базы Shop:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name1` text NOT NULL,
  `act1` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_start` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_finish` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `article` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `map_no_show` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changefreq` enum('always','hourly','daily','weekly','monthly','yearly','never') NOT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `site_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `keywords1` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `descr1` text NOT NULL,
  `title_meta1` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `anons1` text NOT NULL,
  `anons_plus1` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text1` text NOT NULL,
  `yandex` text NOT NULL,
  `show_yandex` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `no_buy` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `import` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `import_id` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sort` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timeedit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `counter_buy` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hit` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `new` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `action` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_file` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `access` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `admin_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `theme` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `view` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `trash` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `canonical1` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `brand_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7929 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

но из этой таблички я могу достать очень мало необходимых мне параметров таких как `name1` и `article`, но мне еще нужно прикрутить к каждому выводу имени свою картинку, но проблема в том что она в другой таблице `images`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `module_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `alt1` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title1` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `element_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `param_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `size` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tmpcode` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `folder_num` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trash` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `element_type` enum('element','cat','brand') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'element'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8607 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

и Мне нужно что бы когда были совпадения по `name1` он сразу смотрел `id` и по этому `id` смотрел в таблицу `images` и там искал `ПЕРВЫЙ element_id` (так как у одного id может быть много картинок) и давал вывод в `name из images` рядом с `name1 из shop` и отправлял все в  `json_encode($arr)`

Comment: Внучка за бабку, Бабка за дедку etc.

Comment: Вопрос в том как объединить в одном запросе несколько таблиц или в чем? Текста много, а смысл неочевиден.

Comment: да, вы правильно поняли, просто на форуме наоборот писали что че так мало и не него не понятно что ты хочешь

Comment: только еще нужно что бы он как то сравнивал 2 столбца и выводил результат из другого по совпадению

Comment: Вопрос можно было разбить на три части: 1) Правильно ли использовать для поиска LIKE в 2015 году? 2) Не могу понять, как в sql создавать relations? 3) Каким образом на клиенте организвать запросы к серверу, чтобы не положить его, возможно, задать некий delay на autocomplete?

Comment: рассмотрю любые наставления и рекомендации, приму любую критику, помогите с правильной реализацией данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев стало понятно, что проблема с объединением таблиц.
Можно сделать как-то так (поля добавьте по вкусу):

```
SELECT
  shop.id, shop.name1,
  images.id AS image_id, images.title1
FROM
  shop JOIN
  images ON (shop.id = images.element_id)
WHERE
  (shop.article LIKE '%$term%') OR (shop.name1 LIKE '%$term%')
```

Проблемы производительности и sql-injection я оставляю за кадром :) Т.к. вопрос был не в этом.

Comment: а можно поподробнее немного расписать, а то с mysql таким обзором очень мало практиковал

Comment: Подробнее тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/123636/
вместо *INNER* JOIN можно писать просто JOIN, как в моем примере.